# SceneKit SCNPhysicsHingeJoint equivalent in RealityKit?

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, scenekit, arkit, realitykit

Is there an equivalent to SceneKit SCNPhysicsBehavior in RealityKit?

I'm attempting to create a chain of multiple Entities but can't seem to find anything similar to SCNPhysicsHingeJoint in RealityKit so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alas! At the moment there are no dynamics constraints in RealityKit.

Comment: Hi Andy Jazz, we now have dynamics in RealityKit. But do we have something similar SCNPhysicsHingeJoint equivalent ?

Comment: Hi @ManeManero, still don't have any... Waiting for RK v3.0.